# Family of polynomials without common zeros

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, noetherian

Can someone help with the following exercise, I really don't know how to approach this:

Let $f_1,...,f_k \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$ be polynomials without common zero $(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

1. Show that there exist $g_1,...,g_k \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$ with $0 \neq g_1f_1+...+g_kf_k \in \mathbb{Z}$
2. Is this still true if $\mathbb{C}^n$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you know of the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: We introduced a very abstract version of the Nullstellensatz with ideals and $k$-algebras , i wouldn't know how to apply it here

Comment: Study the ideal of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ generated by $f_1,\ldots,f_k$.

Comment: @Mindlack  tried doing it, but I don't really know how to apply it here because the polynomials don't have a common zero. Could you explain further? :/

Comment: The Nullstellensatz says that since the polynomials have no common zero, there are $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ with coefficients in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that the sum of the $f_ig_i$ is 1. Then you need to show that the $g_i$ can be taken as rational, then integral, at the cost of turning $1$ into a greater nonzero integer.